# How to install glslc on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, vulkan, glsl

I want to install `glslc` , which is one of the tools of [shaderc](https://github.com/google/shaderc), so I can compile GLSL into Vulkan's `SPIR-V` shader format.

Is there a package that already provides it or I should build  it from source?

Apparently it's not packed on debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890472

I noted it appears to be included in the LunarG Vulkan SDK:
https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.141.2/linux/getting_started.html

From own LunarG website, it's not yet packed for 20.04, only 16.04 and 18.04. This situation may change soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their note is mentioned in [download section](https://github.com/google/shaderc#downloads) is as :
***Note: These binaries are just the artifacts of the builders and have not undergone any QA, thus they should be considered unsupported.***
It means that do not provide binaries and are considered unsupported so there is no other workaround then building the source.

Comment: I ended up building from source, it took me a while to accept this answer because I hoped it would get packed at some point, but it hasn't happened yet.